# Querystring in react-router

Tags: reactjs, query-string, react-router

I am trying to set a Route path with a query string. Something in the lines of:

```
www.mywebsite.com/results?query1=:query1&query2=:query2&query3=:query3
```

I would than transition to the "Results" component like so:

```
<Route path="/" component={Main}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />
  <Route path="results?query1=:query1&query2=:query2&query3=:query3"
    component={SearchResults} />
</Route>
```

In the SearchResults container I would like to be able to have access do query1, query2 and query3 params.

I have not been able to make it work. I get the following error:

> bundle.js:22627 Warning: [react-router] Location
>   "/results?query1=1&query2=2&query3=3" did not match any routes

I tried following the steps in the following guide: (Section: What about query string parameters?)
https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/react-router-an-introduction/

Can I get some help here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using React Router v2.xx, you can access the query parameters via the `location.query` object passed in to your Route component.

In other words, you could rework your route to look like the following:

```
<Route path="results" component={SearchResults} />
```

And then inside your `SearchResults` component, use `this.props.location.query.query1` (similar for `query2` and `query3`) to access the query parameter values.

**EDIT:** This is still the case for React Router v3.xx.

Answer (score 24):

If you're using React Router >= v4 `location.query` is not available anymore. You can plug-in an external library (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string), or use something like this:

```
const search = props.location.search; // could be '?foo=bar'
const params = new URLSearchParams(search);
const foo = params.get('foo'); // bar
```

(just keep in mind that [`URLSearchParams()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) is not supported by Internet Explorer)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about URLSearchParams() and IE

Comment: Also note that if you are using `create-react-app` you must use query-string v5 - `npm install query-string@5`

Comment: Note that you can use this same approach if you're using function components with the `useLocation` hook: `const {search} = useLocation()` and the rest of the code works perfectly :)